# in javascript dom, how do you get the target of the current window?

Tags: javascript, dom, tabs

assuming a link

```
<a href='www.domain.com/mypage' target='target1' >Open in New Tab</a>
```

opens a `mypage`

how, from `mypage`, do I know if the current window is 'target1'

have looked under `window` and `window.location`, but nothing there seems to fit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.name) property is what you're looking for.